# sum() with conditions provides incorrect result in dplyr package

Tags: r, dplyr

When applying `sum()` with conditions in `summarize()` function, it does not provide the correct answer.

Make a data frame x:

```
x = data.frame(flag = 1, uin = 1, val = 2)
x = rbind(x, data.frame(flag = 2, uin = 2, val = 3))
```

This is what x looks like:

```
  flag uin val
1    1   1   2
2    2   2   3
```

I want to sum up the `val` and the `val` with `flag == 2`, so I write

```
x %>% summarize(val = sum(val), val.2 = sum(val[flag == 2]))
```

and the result is:

```
  val val.2
1   5    NA
```

But what I expect is that `val.2` is 3 instead of `NA`. For more information, if I calculate the conditional summation first then the total summation, it comes out with the correct answer:

```
x %>% summarize(val.2 = sum(val[flag == 2]), val = sum(val))
  val.2 val
1     3   5
```

Moreover, if I only calculate the conditional summation, it works fine too:

```
x %>% summarize(val.2 = sum(val[flag == 2]))
  val.2
1     3
```

Comment: I think I have made a stupid mistake. I named the summation result `val`, the same as the name of the variable I used to do the following conditional  summation. If I named it as `val.total`, there will be no calculation error.

Comment: Exactly  - see my answer below

Answer (score 4):

Duplicate names are causing you problems. In this code

```
x %>% summarize(val = sum(val), val.2 = sum(val[flag == 2]))
```

You have two `val` objects. One created from `val = sum(val)` and other from the data frame `x`. In your code, you change `val` from the data frame value to `val=sum(val) = 5`. Then you do

```
`val[flag == 2]`
```

which gives a vector `c(2, NA)`, since `val = 5`. Hence, when you add `2 + NA` you get `NA`. The solution, don't use `val` twice,

```
x %>% summarize(val_sum = sum(val), val.2 = sum(val[flag == 2]))
```